# How to Publish WP original Source metabox value on front-end webpage

Tags: php, metabox

I use a plugin called [WP original Source](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-original-source/).

It lets me add the URL of the original article source, which is handy as it credits the original source of article extracts and summaries that I publish of my website.

This URL is then published as metadata in the source code of my webpage, such as:

```
<meta name="original-source" content="http://www.abc.com.au/article.html">
```

However, I also want to publish this URL at the bottom of the article extract itself, so that users who read the article extract and want more information, can click the link and get taken to the original full article.

I can't work out how to do this however, being only a novice at php.

I did manage to code the following, however instead of getting the URLs, I get the word "array"

```
$originalsource = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_original_source', true);
echo $originalsource;
```

Can someone help me work out what php code I need to insert into the single.php form for the URL of the original source to be published as a visible URL, as well as the metadata statement?

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_meta` is returning an array. Apparently, the plugin is saving `_original_source` as an array.

I don't know what that array looks like but instead of echo do `print_r($original_source);` and you get something that looks like:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
)
```

You can then do something like `echo $original_source['a']` to print "apple".

Comment: Thanks, but as a real novice I am not sure I understand exactly what needs to be placed there.. Can you type out the complete argument I need to use?

Comment: Just replace `echo $original_source;` in you code with `print_r($original_source);` and post the result into your question.

Comment: Wow, you have given me my first real progress in about a days worth of trying.Thank you! This is what has now been published:   Array ( [source1] => http://www.abc.com.au/article.html ) How can I now get rid of the word "array" & "[source1] =>"?

Comment: Hmm, something is just not working. This is my code:

$originalsource = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_original_source', true);
print_r($originalsource);
$echo ['source1'];

I am getting the following result:

Array ( [source1] => abc.com.au/article.html)

What is wrong with my code? BTW, it seems the echo command is not doing anything.

Comment: You want `echo $original_source['source1']`

Comment: It is still just showing the whole line, including "Array ( [source1] => abc.com.au/article.html"

Comment: When I remove the whole line of: print_r($originalsource); then nothing shows when I save and refresh the page.

Comment: This is the code I have, but the echo command does not seem to be working:$originalsource = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_original_source', true);
print_r($originalsource);
echo $original_source['source1'];

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin’s source code:

```
global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_original_source',TRUE);
$s1 = $meta['source1'];
$s2 = $meta['source2'];
$s3 = $meta['source3'];
$s4 = $meta['source4'];
$s5 = $meta['source5'];
```

So it saves up to 5 sources, and you can access these by the names `source1` … `source5` like this:

```
if ( $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_original_source', TRUE) )
{
    $counter = 1;
    $sources = array();

    foreach( $meta as $source )
    {
        $url       = esc_url( $source );
        $sources[] = "<a href='$url'>Source $counter</a>";
        $counter  += 1;
    }

    print "<h3>Sources</h3><ul><li>" . join( "</li><li>", $sources ) . "</li></ul>";
}
```

Comment: Geez, what can I say but a very big thank you. It works perfectly. I really appreciate your assistance.